# Popover covers entire screen iOS

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, popover

I am trying to implement a popover whose anchor is a bar button item for my iphone app. I have connected the bar button item to the view controller via a segue pathway configured as show as "present as popover." I have also set my own size for the view controller and selected "use preferred explicit size." Based on previous posts about this similar topic, I have implemented the following code for my popover. However, the popover is still covering the entire screen, probably because my adaptivePresentationStyle method is not being called ("hello" does not print to the screen). Note that I have also implemented the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate. Where did I go wrong?

```
        override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "popoverLogin" {

        let popoverViewController = segue.destination
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self         }
}

// MARK: - UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Force popover style
    print ("hello")
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**In my case your code works and popover is presented normally!**

[image]

**Make sure your segue has the right "Kind": "Present As Popover".**

[image]

Comment: Yup. I have also added that. My viewcontroller still covers the entire screen. @Alexander Goncharov

Comment: Yup. Tried that too! My popover Viewcontroller still covers the entire screen

Comment: Try to set property popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)

Comment: I added popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(100, 100) because CGSizeMake does not exist. For some reason, the popover still covers the entire screen. I think the problem is that my adaptive method is not getting called because "hello" does not print to the terminal

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: No, it seems problem not in your code. In my case it works perfectly well. Look at my updated answer

Comment: If you want, you can send me your project and I will try to find the issue. (but not now, it's 0:34 AM here).

Comment: Ok thanks! If I still have the issue, I'll send it in about 12 hours or so

Comment: It works now! The problem was I did not identify my segue as "popoverLogin." Thanks for your help!